# How do I teach spam and ham to spamassassin running in a docker container?

Tags: docker, centos7, dovecot, spam, spamassassin

I'm running SpamAssassin as a milter in a Docker container separate from Postfix and Dovecot. Postfix and SA work together nicely, Postfix connects to `spamass-milter`, SA does its thing, mail gets flagged appropriately, all good.

Now, I'd like to be able to teach SA spam from ham when I move messages back and forth between Inbox and Junk, more or less like in [this guide](https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/AntispamWithSieve). I confirmed that sieve works by having a simple filter that moves spam to the Junk folder when flagged so by SA, and it seems to work. Dovecot also runs in its own Docker container.

That guide implies that the `spamc` command can connect to a SA instance via TCP, which would be great if only that didn't mean that I have to have `spamc` available inside the container running Dovecot, which means having to install SA inside that very container, which means in turn lots of unnecessary duplication.

Is there a way around this?

**EDIT** It was suggested that Ubuntu-based containers have a `spamc` package. However, I'm using a CentOS base image, which does not have a separate `spamc` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes there is!**

As you need only `spamc` in your Dovecot container, you should **solely install spamc** and not Spamassassin in the Dovecot container.

**Debian/Ubuntu (Dovecot Container):**

```
apt install spamc
```

**CentOS (Dovecot Container):**

You may install solely spamc with [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) (Python Package Manager).

```
pip install spamc
```

In case your container does not have pip already installed:

Add the EPEL Repository:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Install pip:

```
yum install python-pip
```

And now install spamc with pip as mentioned above.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @RalfFriedl This exactly answers the question. Whether it is a right answer, I cannot say unless I go find a Debian box, but it certainly answered the question.

Comment: OK, Ubuntu has a separate `spamc` package. My container is based on a CentOS 7 image, which does not have a separate `spamc` container. I should have specified that. Sure, I could just base my container on Debian or Ubuntu, but that is non-solution, in general.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Does installing spamc via python-pip solve your problem on CentOS 7? If so, could you please mark the answer as a solution?